# Button causing app crash on launch

Tags: java, android, button, android-fragmentactivity

Hi when I launch my app it crashes instantly reading the logcat I can see that it is cause by the sendButton in my mainActivity, from reading around I people say it has to do with the button not being initiated but as far I can see it is, I have it declared in my fragment_main.xml okay and without the button code in MainActivity.java my code loads the app grand. Any help would really be appreciate.

Logcat

```
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.draco.dragonmessage/com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:178)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5560)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5135)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1151)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
06-20 08:50:18.323: E/AndroidRuntime(30036):    ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.draco.dragonmessage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;
String sendMessageString = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

   final Button sendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.messageButton); 
   System.out.println(sendMessage.toString());
        sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final TextView receivedMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textReceived);
            final EditText messageToSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSend);
            sendMessageString = messageToSend.toString();
            receivedMessage.setText(sendMessageString);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter message to send..." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textReceived"
    android:text="Keith"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textReceived"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextSend"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/messageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextSend"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity" >

<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.draco.dragonmessage.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: have you declared the activity in manifest?

Comment: Yes I did, just checked to make sure, it does work when the button code is removed from the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Button with ID *messageButton* is in fragment_main.xml. With findByViewById() you are accessing to activity_main.xml (`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

You can add an attribute Button to the class and link the element in the onCreateView method of PlaceholderFragment. Then you can access to this button from anywhere in the activity.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked I have been stuck trying to figure this out for months :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Move the following lines to Oncreate() and change R.layout to your fragment layout. You are using a wrong layout

```
final TextView receivedMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textReceived);
 final EditText messageToSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSend);
```

below this one

```
final Button sendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.messageButton);
```

Comment: Hi @Sreejith SP I tried that and it still gives similar logcat '06-20 09:25:56.787: E/AndroidRuntime(31125): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 09:25:56.787: E/AndroidRuntime(31125):  at com.draco.dragonmessage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
'

Comment: change R.layout.activity_main to R.layout.fragment_main
because those buttons are in fragment_main not in activity_main. Now you got NullPointerException